# how to typemap c++ int** return value to python with swig

Tags: python, c++, int, swig

Below is my code：

```
int** myfunction()
{
    int **value = new int*[4];
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        value[i] = new int[4];
        memset(value[i], 0, 4*sizeof(int));
    }
    // asign value

    return value;
}
```

then i want call `myfunction` and get returned `int **` type value with python list,so i add a type map in my `.i` file:

```
%typemap(out) int** {
    $result = PyList_New(4);
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        PyObject *o = PyList_New(4);
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            PyList_SetItem(o,j,PyInt_FromLong((long)$1[i][j]));
        }
        PyList_SetItem($result, i, o);
    }
    delete $1;
}
```

I call `myfunction` in my python code and get nothing. What's incorrect in my code?

Comment: What do you mean with 'nothing'? You get 'None' in your python script? Or you get some zero values? 
By the way, pointer arithmetic is not supported by SWIG, see [doc](http://swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html), section 5.3. I'm not sure what you are trying to do in your python script, but I would expect that you can't iterate through the array in your python script.

Comment: result = myfunction() In my python ,then i make a print, print('result = ', result). and nothing printed. It looks like my c++ function crashed so print not run. I'm trying to get c++ functions return value in my python script. I don't know how to  get a int** return value in python script。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than a memory leak (only deleted the outer `new` not then inner ones), your code looks fine.  Here's what I did:

**test.i**

```
%module test

%typemap(out) int** {
    $result = PyList_New(4);
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        PyObject *o = PyList_New(4);
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            PyList_SetItem(o,j,PyInt_FromLong((long)$1[i][j]));
        }
        delete [] $1[i];
        PyList_SetItem($result, i, o);
    }
    delete [] $1;
}

%inline %{
int** myfunction()
{
    int **value = new int*[4];
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        value[i] = new int[4];
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
            value[i][j] = i*4+j;
    }

    return value;
}
%}
```

Built with SWIG and VS2015 compiler:

```
swig -c++ -python test.i
cl /EHsc /LD /W3 /MD /Fe_test.pyd /Ic:\python36\include test_wrap.cxx -link /libpath:c:\python36\libs
```

Output:

```
>>> import test
>>> test.myfunction()
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15]]
```

Comment: thanks Mark, you are right, calling c++ function from python code cause a core dump, that's why my print not excuted. I'm newbee to swig, it seems ".i" file is just another kind of c++ headers ?

Comment: @yellowfish no .i files are swig interface files. Swig knows how to parse c++ and generate extension code for languages like Python. The .i file controls what to parse and how to generate code with % directives.

Comment: Yeah, i understood. The code i provide creates a int[][] with certain row length and col length, but sometimes i don't know row and col lengths in my python codes, is there anyway to create int[][] according to input parameters?
int** Function(int* row, int* col){*row = GetRow(); *col = GetCol(); //create return int[][].....}

Comment: @yellowfish Tying the creation to input parameters is not straightforward.  Ideally the return value should be a structure containing all the information needed to convert it to a Python object, or create a set of typemaps to handle (int***,int x, int y) and convert the function to return the `int**` as an output parameter instead of a return value.

Comment: Okay, realy thanks for your help. In my project, C++ function creates int** and return it as output to python caller, the size of int** only known by C++ function, with this situation, i think maybe i should use std::vector rather than int**.@Mark Tolonen